# Move an object with csv/txt data - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am trying to move a 3d object using a C# script in Unity3d. The script takes XYZ coordinates from a csv file and then it parses these values to object's position. You can see the script down below:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class lastPSP1 : MonoBehaviour
{   
    
    public TextAsset csvFile;
    
    void update()
    {
        readtxt();
    }
    
    void readtxt()
    {
        string [] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
        for (int i=1; i<records.Length; i++)
        {
            string [] fields = records[i].Split(',');
            
            transform.position = new Vector3(float.Parse(fields[1]),float.Parse(fields[2]),float.Parse(fields[3]));
        }
    }
}
```

My csv looks like that:

```
X,Y,Z
3918625.868,18949220.68,-1281153.635
3912210.028,18950540.5,-1281236.88
3905793.931,18951859.08,-1281320.041
```

I assigned my script to the object,but after I hit play nothing happens. The object remains still. Can you help me please?

Comment: Surely you don't want to parse the same text file _60 times a second?_ (even if it is spelt incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case-sensitive; Unity will search for an `Update` method while you defined an `update` method (notice the different capitalization).
Additionally, you will encounter a [`System.IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-6.0) on this line:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(float.Parse(fields[1]),float.Parse(fields[2]),float.Parse(fields[3]));
```

You have three fields, but you're ignoring the first field and trying to use the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th (non-existent) field. Remember; array indexing starts from 0.

Also, as you're executing the whole for-loop without any waits in the `Update()` method, you will only see the last position being used. In order to fix this, you'd need to either distribute the call over several update calls (this would mean a delay of a single game frame between setting each position), or by using a coroutine (most probably what you want).

```
public class lastPSP1 : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public TextAsset csvFile;
    
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ReadTxt());
    }
    
    IEnumerator ReadTxt()
    {
        string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fields = records[i].Split(',');
            
            transform.position = new Vector3(float.Parse(fields[0]), float.Parse(fields[1]), float.Parse(fields[2]));

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // this is the delay between each position change
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `async/await` is the contemporary way to perform asynchronous operations compared to coroutines which merely multiplex execution and piggy-backing on the UI thread.

Comment: Not only you answered simply, correctly and so quickly, you also were so polite and on point! I can't thank you enough for that, your code worked like a charm and after three days I have a working moving object the way I want it. HATS OFF